# Change password of another user using FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have two roles in my system: users and admins. By default, when someone logs in as an user or an admin, he can modify his own password using the implemented forms of FOSUserBundle. But I'd like to forbid the users to change their own password, having to request it to the admin, so then the admin would reset it, either introducing a new one chosen by the admin, either generating a random one. I'd also like to send and a email to the user telling him that his passwd has changed and he has to use the new one from now on. But I cannot find how do that. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

If you want an admin to change another user's password, you can use your own form:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username',               TextType::class, array(
                                                    'required' => true,
                                                    'label' => "Username "
                                                    ))
            ->add('email',                  TextType::class, array(
                                                    'required' => true,
                                                    'label' => "Adresse email "
                                                    ))
            ->add('plainPassword',          RepeatedType::class, array(
                                                    'type' => PasswordType::class,
                                                    'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                                                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                                                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                                                    'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                                                    ))
            ->add('roles',                  ChoiceType::class, array(
                                                    'required' => true,
                                                    'choices' => array('Salarié' => 'ROLE_SALARIE', 'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
                                                    'multiple' => true,
                                                    'expanded'=>true,
                                                    'label' => "Rôle ",
                                                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'checkbox-inline')
                                                    ))
        ;
    }
```

//...

And then, in your controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, Member $user)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createEditForm($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $userManager->updatePassword($user);
        $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent users from changing their password by removing the `fos_user_change_password` and `fos_user_resetting` routes in your `app/config/routing.yml` file. This way neither users nor admin will be able to change their own password through the `/profile` page.

Then you will need to create a secured controller action that allows admin to change passwords and send the email. In order to do that you can use FOSUserBundle `UserManager` and its `setPlainPassword()` method.

Take a look at the documentation:

[Symfony2 Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

[FOSUserBundle User Manager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md)

[How to send an Email](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html)