# symfony 2/3: how to reset password via API ?

Tags: passwords, symfony

I'm using for my app's backend FOS User Bundle, FOS Rest Bundle and FOS Oauth Bundle. These work ok. Now I want to create an API that permit my user's app to change their password without the old password field.

I have searched on internet but I have not found document/web page about how to change password via API or code but always without old_password field.

If not exist: if I create an api that get (via $request) password and password_confirm how can I validate it ? I have found only docs that require old password field.

Thanks.

Comment: [Example of password update using userManager without old password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042988/change-password-of-another-user-using-fosuserbundle)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but the first line of that code (that I have see before write my post) is "If you want an admin to change another user's password," BUT in my post I have write "that permit my user's app to change their password "... Not ADMIN.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user->setPlainPassword($new);
$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updatePassword($user);
$um->updateUser($user);
```

I have this running on production environment. Very similar to the other proposed solution. FosUserBundle doesn't check permissions to do this operations, that's your responsability at controller or custom manager level.